# Parameter Passing Issue with Servlet

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets, netbeans

I have created a Web Application Project and Java Application Project using NetBeans 6.9. Now, my project structure is like,

```
Web Application Project 
    WEB-INF
        JSP Page
    Source Package
        Servlet

Java Application Project
     default package
             Java File
```

Now, I want to pass parameters from Servlet/JSP to Java file (in both direction). Can anybody help me, how can I solve this ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that servlets mist not live in the default package; they must be in a named package. Also, of you're trying to import classes in your JSP you might be doing it wrong--Java code should live in Java files and JSPs should be as "dumb" as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parameter passing to the JSP/Servlet will most likely be done via request parameters (or possibly session parameters. This is done in the construction of your query string.

For example;

```
/mywebapp/MyJsp.jsp?param1=param1Value&param2=param2Value
```

The same query strings can be used in the case of Servlets. The Servlets simply need to be configured in your web.xml This is done via the 
`<servlet>` and `<servlet-mapping>` tags within the web.xml.

Both the JSP and Servlet files should be able to import and reference the methods of your "Java File" under the default pacakage that you mentioned. The can directly call methods in your classes assuming that the Java file is on your classpath (either as a class file or in a JAR file).

Take a look at some introductory tutorials on developing a web-app and you'll soon get some examples of how this all works.

Comment: Thanks. But, I am not finding how to import java file in servlet/jsp.

Comment: If you're using tomcat you can find them in the lib directory. You need to include the servlet and jsp .jar files.

Comment: You can read up on import declarations here -> http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/packages.doc.html#70209 Note what Dave Newton said in his comment on your question though too. Ideally, you don't want to have Java code in your JSP. It is possible, but it isn't ideal. Some basic introductions regarding Java web application structure would be good. Best of luck.